# Loop For (It is necessary to compare the value)

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop

Loop For (It is necessary to compare the value)

I have 2 dataframes.

It is necessary to compare the value from the first dataframe with the values from the second and assign classes according to it.

For example. Dataframe a with 1 column e.

Dataframe b

[image]

Need to create a column `a$c`, where `if a$e<b$from & a$b>b$to`, then the corresponding `b$m` is assigned.

```
    for (i in a$e){
       for (j in b$from ){
         for (k in b$to){
           for (m in b$m ){
             a$c<-ifelse(a$e<b$from & a$b>b$to, b$m ,0)

        }

      }

    }

  }

}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work out. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Did your instructor ask you to use for loops?

Comment: So what't the desired output here?

Comment: @MrFlick  for a$e= 5, class 2 will be assigned, since 5 falls within the range of the dataframe b ( b$from, b$to) and is equal to class 2

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover, not necessarily, but some libraries (for example tdvyrse ) I can't have installed in the workplace

Comment: What happens with a$e==4? Why can't you use tidyverse functions? This will not be very easy with base R.

Comment: @MrFlick I created these datasets as a sample. In real datasets, all values fall into ranges. I can't install the tidyverse in the near future due to security policy. And how would you see the solution in tidyverse?

Comment: @Olesia whom is saying you can't install extra packages? Only a class instructor would say "do it this certain way". In a career setting, this wouldn't be the case.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover, I work in environments where one cannot just "install packages" due to security policies. Trying to workaround either one can get me fired in one work-center (corporate) or arrested in the other (us-govt scif). While it is usually a classroom environment (and I am not fond of using R to teach basic CS principles), there are perfectly valid professional environments that restrict packages and net-access.

Answer (score 1):

This really should be a range-join, but we can hack it since it's a single-key join.

Up front, I'm going to assume that there is never overlap that would suggest more than one `class` can be assigned. I'll guard against it (so that we don't have problems), but I'll also discard if/when it happens.

```r
a <- data.frame(e=4:6)
b <- data.frame(classes=1:3, from=c(2,5,8), to=c(3,7,10))
```

## base R

```r
a$class <- b$classes[sapply(a$e, function(x) which(b$from <= x & x <= b$to)[1])]
a
#   e class
# 1 4    NA
# 2 5     2
# 3 6     2
```

---

If overlaps are possible, then we can do more, but we need to shift into the realm of "list-columns":

```r
b$from[3] <- 6
a$class <- lapply(a$e, function(x) b$classes[which(b$from <= x & x <= b$to)])
a
#   e class
# 1 4      
# 2 5     2
# 3 6  2, 3
str(a)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ e    : int  4 5 6
#  $ class:List of 3
#   ..$ : int 
#   ..$ : int 2
#   ..$ : int  2 3
```

In this case, note that while `a$e[2]` is a vector of length 1, `a$class[2]` is always a `list`. If you want to look at a single value, you need to use `[[` in lieu of `[`. Also note that `a$class[[1]]` is a length-0 (empty) vector.

```r
a$class[[1]]
# integer(0)
a$class[3]
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 3
a$class[[3]]
# [1] 2 3
```

This does not work well with many base functions such as `summary` and `lm`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything works perfectly with sapply! You are great!